# How to properly synchronize vkAcquireNextImageKHR and vkCmdBeginRenderPass?

Tags: vulkan

I have a simple render pass that draws to color & depth attachments.

My sequence of commands is roughly like so:

```
target_ready_semaphore = vkAcquireNextImageKHR()
vkBeginRenderPass()
// no draw calls at the moment
vkEndRenderPass()
 
vkQueueSumbit(target_ready_semaphore ) // submit to the graphics queue
```

When activating the synchronization validation via the vulkan configurator, I get the following validation error immediately after the first submit call (no presentation yet):

```
Validation Error: [ SYNC-HAZARD-WRITE-AFTER-READ ] Object 0: handle = 0x1d70a7b70d0, type = VK_OBJECT_TYPE_QUEUE; | MessageID = 0x376bc9df | vkQueueSubmit:
 Hazard WRITE_AFTER_READ for entry 0, VkCommandBuffer 0x1d70d0fe7b0[], Recorded access info (recorded_usage: SYNC_IMAGE_LAYOUT_TRANSITION, command: vkCmdBeginRenderPass,
 seq_no: 1,renderpass: VkRenderPass 0x67022e000000004b[], reset_no: 1). Access info (prior_usage: SYNC_PRESENT_ENGINE_SYNCVAL_PRESENT_ACQUIRE_READ_SYNCVAL,
 read_barriers: VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT|VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_2_BOTTOM_OF_PIPE_BIT, , batch_tag: 7, vkAcquireNextImageKHR aquire_tag:7:
 VkSwapchainKHR 0x603cd90000000044[], image_index: 0image: VkImage 0x8cc1d80000000045[]).
```

I struggle to understand this error message.
My understand is that this probably has something to do with `vkAcquireNextImageKHR` which is a device function and `vkBeginRenderPass`. But my understanding is that the render pass should synchronize the access to the color attachment by itself according to the `VkAttachmentDescription` structure:

```
VkAttachmentDescription
        {
            .format = config.color_output_format,
            .samples = VkSampleCountFlagBits::VK_SAMPLE_COUNT_1_BIT,
            .loadOp = VkAttachmentLoadOp::VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_CLEAR,
            .storeOp = VkAttachmentStoreOp::VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_STORE,
            .stencilLoadOp = VkAttachmentLoadOp::VK_ATTACHMENT_LOAD_OP_DONT_CARE,
            .stencilStoreOp = VkAttachmentStoreOp::VK_ATTACHMENT_STORE_OP_DONT_CARE,
            .initialLayout = VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_UNDEFINED,
            .finalLayout = VkImageLayout::VK_IMAGE_LAYOUT_PRESENT_SRC_KHR
        };
```

And here is my `VkSubpassDependency`:

```
       VkSubpassDependency subpassDependency
        {
            .srcSubpass = VK_SUBPASS_EXTERNAL,
            .dstSubpass = 0,
            .srcStageMask = VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT, // wait for previously issued depth tests to finish, note we don't wait for color
            .dstStageMask = VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_EARLY_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT | VkPipelineStageFlagBits::VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_OUTPUT_BIT, // don't start depth test / color clear before previously depth writes are done and subpass image transition is done
            .srcAccessMask = VkAccessFlagBits::VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT, // previous render pass writes to the same depth buffer
            .dstAccessMask = VkAccessFlagBits::VK_ACCESS_COLOR_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT | VkAccessFlagBits::VK_ACCESS_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT_WRITE_BIT,
            .dependencyFlags = {},
        };
```

So what else could be missing?
How to properly synchronize vkAcquireNextImageKHR and vkCmdBeginRenderPass?

Comment: Ok , your `srcStage` is `VK_PIPELINE_STAGE_LATE_FRAGMENT_TESTS_BIT`. In which stage your submission waits on the semaphore? Before or after that?